# Math problems in Java; uncanny NaN from a calculation

Tags: java, math, logarithm

I am working on a project that does a lot of querying and the some mathematical modeling based on results from these queries, and finally some scoring (read: "execution time too long to test thoroughly").

Recently I have realized a rather new problem/bug in my code; some of the results get `NaN` values for score! Here's how the scores are calculated:

Note that `pfound`, `psig` are `double`s that are always positive or 0

```
Double  score1 = (pfound!=0) ? (Math.log(factorial((int)psig + 1))/pfound) : 0;

score1 = score1 * alpha_coeff[0];
if (score1.isInfinite())
    throw new RuntimeException(p.getName() + " score1 = Inf");
else if(score1.isNaN())
    throw new RuntimeException(p.getName() + " score1 = NaN");
```

I have checked the possible causes triggering `NaN`, but I believe it should be safe from most of those:

1. I am already checking for pfound == 0 (so no divide by zero)
2. Argument to Math.log() cannot have a negative value

What I suspect is whether or not `factorial()` (a custom function which return the factorial as a `long`) returns a `long` so big that it can't be cast into a `double` without loss of precision or something like that. I checked `Long.doubleValue()`, and apparently it generates `NaN` if it's argument results in `NaN`.

Any comments? Am I missing something fundamental here?

Comment: Don't worry about casting the long to a double - this is always safe in the sense that it won't produce NaN, although you might lose some low order precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NaNs propagate through various arithmetic operations so even if you are checking the conditions here correctly they could be getting introduced from elsewhere.

I'd suspect either alpha_coeff[0] or pfound - try checking these for NaN.

NaN could also be a result from your factorial function, depending on how this is defined. EDIT: just noticed that you specified that this produces a long, so factorial can't produce a NaN, on the other hand it could produce a negative result if it overflows which would cause a NaN from the log().

Comment: p.s. note that 0 != NaN, so if pfound is NaN then the first half of your condition gets executed. This will then produce NaN as the overall result.

Comment: alpha_coeff.s are all positive doubles between 0-1.. so thats safe too.. 
as for the factorial(), i think you might be onto something, I checked a bit more and it appears that the largest value they can hold is 2^63-1 which translates to something like E18. Gotta check if my factorial goes above that.. 

ps: does anyone know how to typeset the comments so that gray background shows for the code related stuff like NaN

Comment: If factorial is overflowing you could get a negative value, which would result in NaN from the log() function.....

Comment: OK, it turns out that the value factorial should return is around E32 which is clearly over the max value for Long. If I use `BigInteger` instead for my factorial function, can I send it to `Math.log()` just like a long?

Comment: Yep, you should be able to use BigInteger, you'll probably need to apply BigInteger.doubleValue() at some point to convert to double before doing the log.

Answer (score 3):

If your factorial is doing the naive evaluation of x! = 1*2*3..., I'll bet you're asking for a factorial of a number that can't fit into the reference you're using.

Two pieces of advice:

1. Try BigDecimal if that's the case
2. Use [gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) instead of naive implementation.

Recursion for factorial(n) where n > 12 is a very bad, naive idea.  You weren't seriously thinking about going forward with something like this, were you?

Comment: yes it is a very simple recursive function, and yes again, it does most likely cause an overflow as mentioned in my comment to @mikera's post above. It's very interesting that you mention the gamma function, I have not thought of that before :) Could you possibly comment on the performance of an implementation of that instead of the recursive factorial method. Oh, and lastly, I guess regardless what I use, I still need `BigInteger`, right?

Comment: No, BigDecimal. The gamma function is more general than the naive factorial. Gamma's different because it's not recursive: you pass it an argument and the value comes back. There's a nice implementation in "Numerical Recipes". You can also check out Abramowitz and Stegun.  Or this: http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/FastFactorialFunctions.htm

Comment: A factorial should be a lookup table, not computed at run-time.

Comment: hmm, thanks for the links. turns out an implementation of `logGamma()` is implemented readily in Apache Commons Math package which I have already implemented. Then n! = `Math.exp(logGamma(n+1))` should solve my problems?

Comment: i just realized that I dont need the exp function at all, thanks a lot for the help on the factorial!

Comment: @Hamish - How many values in your lookup table?  I agree that it can help, but it's not the whole solution.  Especially if the argument can be non-integer.  Gamma solves both.

Comment: @duffy, ok, for non-integers - sure. But for integers, `100 ! = 9.33262154 x 10^157` so pre-computing and caching them starts to make sense for practical uses.

Comment: @Hamish - I think our solutions work together assuming that your lookup is really a cache.  The use case would be: request a value for the parameter key; look up in table.  If it doesn't appear, calculate using gamma and cache; if it does appear, return and done.

Comment: Ah, memoization then - ok, we do have a deal. How fast does the implementation of a gamma function compute values?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't compare doubles against zero explicitly - it almost never works. Better do something like this:

```
double EPS = 0.0000001;
if (Math.abs (pfound) < EPS) { //pfound is null }
```

The only place I see which can produce NaN is `Math.log`. From its documentation:

> 1. If the argument is NaN or less than zero, then the result is NaN.
> 2. If the argument is positive infinity, then the result is positive
>      infinity.
> 3. If the argument is positive zero or negative zero, then the result is
>      negative infinity.

I think `pfound` contains negative value neer zero and that's why you get NaN. Try to track variable values in a debugger.

Comment: Further to the above, if they (pFound, psig) are always positive or zero, why are you using a Double?

Comment: great call with pfound, and psig, i see no reason why they should be double, must have lost track of things there.. they are now int.s anyhow..

Comment: when dealing with Java, it's usually best not to think (or suggest) that "null" and "0" are the same thing.  A double cannot be assigned a value of null, but it can be assigned a value of 0.